# Print List string in new line in chart legends

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, charts, datatable, legend

I have a list of strings which I am printing in the chart legends.
I want to print the string in the list one below the other in the chart legends

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

if (table7.Columns.Contains(colx))
{
    for (int yy = 0; yy < table7.Rows.Count; yy++)
    {

        double tval = double.Parse(table7.Rows[yy][colx].ToString());

        if (tval < lower || tval > upper)
        {

            list.Add(table7.Rows[yy]["Die_ID"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

//strings in the list are printed in a single line I want to print each of them one after the other

```
LegendItem firstItem = new LegendItem();
Font f = new Font("Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

foreach (string s in list)
{
      LegendCell firstCell = new LegendCell(LegendCellType.Text, "" + s, ContentAlignment.BottomRight);

      firstCell.Font = f;
      firstItem.Cells.Add(firstCell);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        LegendItem firstItem = new LegendItem();
        Font f = new Font("Serif", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

        LegendCell firstCell = new LegendCell();


        for (int l = 0; l < list.Count;l++ )
        {

            firstCell.Text = list[l] + Environment.NewLine  +firstCell.Text;

            firstCell.Font = f;

        } firstItem.Cells.Add(firstCell);
```